# Ruby on Rails show.html.erb undefined method `naam' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I created a basic application for learning purposes.

When a record is created I redirect to show action and get an error: undefined method `naam' for nil:NilClass.

What am I doing wrong?

**rake routes**

```
     Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)     welcome#index
     relaties GET    /relaties(.:format)          relaties#index
              POST   /relaties(.:format)          relaties#create
   new_relaty GET    /relaties/new(.:format)      relaties#new
  edit_relaty GET    /relaties/:id/edit(.:format) relaties#edit
       relaty GET    /relaties/:id(.:format)      relaties#show
              PATCH  /relaties/:id(.:format)      relaties#update
              PUT    /relaties/:id(.:format)      relaties#update
              DELETE /relaties/:id(.:format)      relaties#destroy
         root GET    /                            welcome#index
```

**relaties_controller.rb**

```
class RelatiesController < ApplicationController

def new
    @relatie = Relatie.new
end

def create
    @relatie = Relatie.new(relatie_params)
    @relatie.save
    redirect_to @relatie
end

    private
      def relatie_params
        params.require(:relatie).permit(:id, :naam, :straatnaam, :huisnummer, :postcode, :plaats, :omschrijving)    
      end   

    def show
        @relatie = Relatie.find(params[:id])
    end 
 end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  resources :relaties   
  root 'welcome#index'
```

**show.html.erb**

```
    <p>
  <strong>Naam:</strong>
  <%= @relatie.naam %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Straatnaam:</strong>
  <%= @relatie.straatnaam %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Huisnummer:</strong>
  <%= @relatie.huisnummer %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Postcode:</strong>
  <%= @relatie.postcode %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Plaats:</strong>
  <%= @relatie.plaats %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Omschrijving:</strong>
  <%= @relatie.omschrijving %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error you've provided, it indicates that there is no `naam` method for `nil:NilClass`. What this means is that you're calling a method that doesn't exist for the given object (nil). Looking at your code, this means `@relatie` is not being set correctly in `show`. I.e. `Relaties.find(params[:id])` is returning `nil`.

This is most likely an error with `@relatie.save`, which is failing, causing your `redirect_to @relatie` to redirect for `nil`. Looking at your `create` and `rake routes` are you sure you shouldn't be using `Relaty.new` and not `Relaties.new`?

as @RedZagogulin mentioned, the source of the error is that your `show` is defined UNDER the `private` tag, meaning that `show` is a private method and not accessible by the call. Therefore, `@relatie` is NOT being set. Simply moving it above the tag should solve your problem.

Comment: I am not sure what you meen, but when I change Relaties.new to Relaty.new in de Create action I get an error when submitting the form.

Comment: Your `show` action has to be defined *above* the `private`, not under.